# In a Google Script, call a function by its name, given its name in a string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have tried the code examples that I found here on the "stackoverfllow" site, related to calling a function from a string. They don't seem to work in a Google App Script. I receive an error to effect that "window" as an undefined object.

Here is the situation that I am trying to solve. 
I have a spreadsheet that is going to have many different
sheets. Some of these sheets will have names that are known 
at the time I write the code. Other sheets will have names that are not known
exactly at the time I write the code (e.g. based on dynamic data).

The current documentation tells me that the name of the "onEdit" event
handler is "onEdit".  Since thee name is unique, I conclude that there
can only be one such routine with this name within a spreadsheet application.

Because of this situation (above) I would like reduce the complexity of my
"onEdit" function. I would like to write the "onEdit" routine
to do "dynamic" calls to sub-functions which use qualified names,
based upon the name of the "sheet" in which the edit event occurred.

Here is a pseudo code example of the "onEdit" routine I want to right.

```
  function onEdit(src)
  {
     var act_sheet = src.getActiveSheet();
     var sheet_name = act_sheet.getName();
     var rtn_name = "onEdit_sheet_".sheet_name;

     if ( function_exists(rtn_name) )
     {
         window[rtn_name](srv)
     }
  }
```

I have actually tried similar code. In the google environment the "window" object is flagged as an unknown object.

Is there some other "object" name in the environment that I should be using?
Is this possible within the Google Apps Script environment?

---

In addition, I know that the "function_exists" routine is also a challenge to write.
That will be my next question. I know about the "typeof" operation, it 
returns "string" when I code

```
      "if ( typeof rtn_name == function" ) .. "
```

Is there a way to test that a routine exists given a name contained in a string?

---

I know I can use "static" names and hard code them in the "onEdit" routine.
But I would like to write the routine once, and not have to modify it 
for each new spreadsheet that I write.  In stead of writing very 
complicated "onEdit" routines, I want to concentrate on writing 
and testing "onEdit" functions for individual sheet's.

I understand Javascript within a browser environment. The Google apps
script environment is more of a mystery to me. I find the documentation
very very terse, and in need of fuller explanations. Any additional
information about what objects exist in the Google apps script environment
would be helpful.

---

Of course my third step might be to write an "onEdit" routine that 
dispatches the correct sub-function based upon the current "range"
associated with an Edit event.

---

I am NEW to Google Apps Scripts. I am looking for a script solution.
It probably can be done in "Java", but that is beyond the scope in which
I want to code.

---

I am also new to the "stackoverflow" environment. Much of it seems a 
mystery to me. (e.g. How do I specify which tags should be associated
with this question? How do I know which tags are available to be assigned 
to this question? How do I limit my search to certain tags? - I am 
at the moment interested in "google apps scripts", when I select the
"javascript" button in the right column it takes me into a javascript
answers which may not apply to the google script environment. Found out
how to "assign" tags below. How do I know which tags are available without
just guessing?

All and any help is appreciated.

Comment: You specify the tags when you create the question. You can see existing tags [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags), or create new ones when you have enough reputation. You can limit your searches to certain tags by adding the tag in `[` square brackets `]` to your query. Most of the time, you do just guess tags; just think about what your question relates to and see if a tag exists for that. I think you did pretty well tagging your question.

Comment: What happens if you add `var global = this;` at the top of the script and use `global` rather than `window`?

Comment: Shouldn't `var rtn_name = "onEdit_sheet_".sheet_name;` actually be `var rtn_name = "onEdit_sheet_" + sheet_name;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know two ways to call the function using its name on a string in Apps Script.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var func = 'test';
  this[func]();
  //eval(func+'()'); //msgBox and eval don't play nice together
  Browser.msgBox('finished');
}

function test() {
  Browser.msgBox('test');
}
```

Of course, when using the `this` approach, you should not be in another scope, e.g. from a function called using `new`. But this exact full code that I'm posting works fine.

Comment: @just.a.guy it seems that you're new to stackoverflow. you should check an answer as accept when you feel you got a good one.

Comment: Abreu, I tried both options "this" and "eval". Neither worked correctly. The "this" reference was reported as an undefined object. The "eval" option was caught in the test environment as violating some interpreter rule. Run in a spreadsheet as an "onEdit" routine. The dynamic routine was called and executed at least one statement. But the "eval" statement never returned to the calling routine.

Comment: Here is the code I used:                                                                                                             function onEdit(src)
{
   var fn = 'ddd'
 //  this[fn]() 
     eval(fn+"()")
   Browser.msgBox("type of xfn is "+fn)    
}

function ddd()
{
  Browser.msgBox("hello world")
}

Comment: I am sure it's a problem on your code, as this statements work fine. Does your function execute normally when you run them directly? Also, are you getting this error messages on the email? Because one can't see the error reports on the script editor, as you're not triggering it manually. Do you know the `onEdit` function have limited permissions? And when you run the code directly you have full permissions?

Comment: You don't need to sue both methods. You'll just trigger the `ddd` function twice. Also, Browser.msgBox is not permitted under `onEdit` functions (unless you're running them directly, but it will not work when it's running automatically triggered by an actual edit).

Comment: The code in the example scripts does not use a ";" to end a statement. So I am following their examples. The comment above removed all carriage-returns. the "// this[fn]()" statement is on one line. the "eval..." is on a following line. Assume normal formatting.

Comment: Here is what I understand you to say: you cannot call the msgBox" function from an "eval" function. But you can call it from the "onEdit" function. The purpose of this onEdit routine is to allow the subfunction to act as if it was called as a handler. This makes the scope and contents of the subfunction less complex. If you cannot do the same thing that the onEdit routine can do, it is less useful.

Comment: If you are saying that the msgBox routine will not work in the "onEdit" function when it is triggered in an actual spreadsheet, I must disagree. I ran an "onEdit" function that consisted of two msgBox statement in a real spreadsheet and they both were executed correctly.

Comment: Aside: I guess I am using comments in the wrong way. I am new and do not know any other way. I tried moving to "chat" but it says I donot have enough reputation points. Sorry - if you know another way please let me know.

Comment: My mistake about msgBox and onEdit. They do work together. About the comments, that's ok. No other way indeed. I edit my answer include a full code example, please try it.

Comment: Abreu, Thank you very much it did work. I tried a similar script. But I received an error. I wonder if it is because of the missing ";"? The tutorial examples do not include ";", so I thought they were not allowed. Your example worked great!!!! thanks again.

Comment: The usage of semicolons on Apps Script is the same as in any javascript. It's not forbidden nor required, but has some "tricks" when one do not use them. I always use it, I consider a "good practice". If you're interested on the topic, do a Google Search. I'm sure there's someone even here on Stackoverflow that explain it beautifully.

Comment: two ways?! There is one and not working for me, yet!

Comment: `this[func]()` did not work for me because `this` is undefined.
What worked for me was these two: ``eval(`${func}()`)`` or 'eval(func+'()')`
During execution `eval()` passes `func()` to the javascript engine to be run as javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

For ES8:

```
var GoogleAppsScrip = this;
function onEdit(e) {
  var func = 'test';
  GoogleAppsScrip[func]();
  Browser.msgBox('finished');
}
```

Comment: you can write directly `this[func]()`

Answer (score -1):

If you know where the function is stored at you can do a standard if check.

```
if(window.myFunction){//then do something};


      function someFunction(){

        if(this.florida.miami.beach.girls.boobs > 'b')
        {
                alert('Get Plane Ticket!');
        }
         else{
               console.log('improvise')};
        };


        if(window.someFunction){

        window.someFunction.call(new USA());
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This looks like an answer that would work in a browser environment. I don't know that it will work as a Google Apps script in a spreadsheet. It uses the same qualifier "window" which seems not to be defined in the google apps script enviornment. I could be wrong. You also use the "alert" function. In the google apps script environment you have to use the "Browser.msgBox(...)" function to accomplish the same thing.